# How to keep multiple buttons inline in a form?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a form using html and css.
But when I keep multiple buttons inside the form tag, they act as a submit button even though one out of it was used for going back. If I keep the another button outside the form tag then the button is placed at the new line but I want both the buttons in the same line.

```html
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <label class="label">
            email:
            <input type="email" name="email"
             placeholder="example@gmail.com"
             maxlength="40" required>
        </label>
        <label class="label">
            password:
            <input type="password" name="password"
             required>
        </label>
        <input class="submit" type="submit">
    </form>
   <a href="index.php"><button>Back</button></a>
```

Help me in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default buttons in a form is type submit, so all you need to do is change the type of the button to button (`<button type="button">Back</button>`).
like this:

```html
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <label class="label">
            email:
            <input type="email" name="email"
             placeholder="example@gmail.com"
             maxlength="40" required>
        </label>
        <label class="label">
            password:
            <input type="password" name="password"
             required>
        </label>
        <input class="submit" type="submit">
        <a href="index.php"><button type="button">Back</button></a> 
    </form>
```